# Is there a typescript trick to require an argument in implementation of object method?

Tags: typescript

Is there a typescript trick to make the following give an TS error?

```
interface IFoo {
  update: (time: number) => void;
}

const foo: IFoo = {
  update: () => {} // <-- I want this to error from lack of number arg
};
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do this, however it is not something I can see a need for. Why do you want to have this restriction?

Comment: @MikeJerred Why? Because I am implementing a class of entity in an animation, and when I loop through all such entities I want to call entity.update(time), and if I forget to implement update as a function of this time parameter, my whole approach won't work properly. Also, for people who use my code, it will be helpful to them to understand how everything works by being told that they HAVE to implement this method, and that it HAS to receive this parameter; else they might try implementing this method based on a misunderstanding of how updates work.

Comment: You can certainly require that the `update` function is implemented - this is already so in the code you provided since update is not an optional member of the interface. This is entirely different to requiring the function use the parameter passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an option to do this that I'm aware of, and it would be highly undesirable to enable such an option. Consider the code below:

```
function add1(x: number): number {
    return x + 1;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = arr.map(add1);
```

This code is straightforwardly correct, but the `add1` function is missing some parameters that are part of the callback signature for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map); the callback can take up to 3 parameters: the element from the array, its index, and a reference to the array itself. If your suggested compiler option were enabled, then the code above would have an error because the `add1` function doesn't declare all three parameters in its signature.

Comment: Yep. I get this and hence why it is generally undesirable to require arguments. But I was wondering if there is a trick for particular/isolated circumstances where I really do want to require the argument be supplied.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, unfortunately. Please check this out:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30876

This kind of strict function implementation in typescript was not approved.